# How to connect my own dns server(bind9) to global domain(for example go_daddy)

Tags: dns, bind, domain-name, bind9

I have bought the domain name from a name domain register. And I have my own DNS server (Bind9) with global IP. Explain to me please, how to connect my domain to my bind server IP address. In my domain register a personal account, I just can add only my own Custom name service, not IP. How global users can be forwarded to my bind9 server to get IP address of the service described there?

Comment: Do I solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You must add your `NS` records to point you'r own domain name at your Registrar (as you called it: "domain register a personal account").

Example, if my domain is `Example.com` and I have a server at IP `1.1.1.1`.

Since you're trying to create a NameServer.

You must for example choose an NS name like `ns1` so, it will be something like: `ns1.example.com`. This must be the NameServer records for your domain at your registrar.

Then you must add another NS record, but since I assume you only have one server (Bad Practice), you must add the same server with ex: `ns2.example.com`.

So at this point it should be something like.

```
example.com IN   NS   ns1.example.com
example.com IN   NS   ns2.example.com
```

Then, you must create a `Glue` record with your registrar. So for them to know that
`ns1.example.com` points to `1.1.1.1` and `ns2.example.com` points to `1.1.1.1`.

This action will make that the registrar updates the `Root Servers` with your pointing records for your NameServers.